# Why my memoization code written in c not working?

Tags: c, recursion, memoization

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int memo[100];
```

Below is the function in which memoization is used.

I am trying to store the return value of redundent recursive calls in memo[n] array at the nth position.

```
int rec(int n){
    if(n<=2)
        return 0;
    
    if(memo[n]!= -1)
        return memo[n];
    
    memo[n]= rec(n-2)+(n/2)-1;
    printf("%d",memo[n]);
    return memo[n];
}
```

Below is the main() function.
I have initialized all the values of memo[] array to -1.

```
void main(){
 
    int n,t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--){
        scanf("%d",&n);

        if(n%2!=0)
            n=n-1;

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            memo[i]= -1;
        }
        printf("\n%d",rec(n));
    }

}
```

It is giving output as 0 (zero).
I am unable to find out what's wrong with this code. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

> I have initialized all the values of memo[] array to -1.

No, you have not. The loop `for(int i=0;i<n;i++)` does not initialize `memo[n]`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now it is solved. Thanx for help.